# find the number of continuous records

Tags: mysql, sql

if I have a table with filenames such as

```
filenames
1201
1202
1203
1205
1207
1208
1301
1302
1303
1304
1305
1306
```

and I want the result to be

```
 sequences grouped , count
      12              3
      12              1
      12              2
      13              6
```

or something like that.

otherwise i just extract the column and do it in python or something ?

Comment: Are the file names always going to be 4 characters long?

Comment: Could there be 1299,1300? What would happen then?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by enumerating the rows and then taking the difference.  In MySQL, you use variables for the enumeration:

```
select min(filename) as first_filename, max(filename) as last_filename, count(*) as num
from (select t.*, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
      from table t cross join (select @rn := 0) vars
     ) t
group by (filename - rn);
```

Note that this sort of assumes that `filename` is a number -- after all, what does consecutive mean for other types?  If it is an integer represented as a string, then this will still work.

Comment: well my filename is a text and is parsed as a number with right(filename,4) so am not able to use the cast to int on it and am not getting the result. my filename is xxxxxxx1201 :(

Comment: Your question specifies that the filename consists only of integers.  If these are the last four characters, then use this solution with `right(filename, 4)`.  It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the records is the same you could use

```
LEFT(filenames, 2)
```

this will give you the corresponding front two numbers. Then use

```
RIGHT(filenames, 1)
```

And this will give your the corresponding last number.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1201),
 (1202),
 (1203),
 (1205),
 (1207),
 (1208),
 (1301),
 (1302),
 (1303),
 (1304),
 (1305),
 (1306);

 SELECT a.id start
      , MIN(c.id) - a.id + 1 cnt
   FROM my_table a
   LEFT 
   JOIN my_table b 
     ON b.id + 1 = a.id 
   LEFT 
   JOIN my_table c
     ON c.id >= a.id 
   LEFT 
   JOIN my_table d 
     ON d.id - 1 = c.id 
  WHERE b.id IS NULL 
    AND c.id IS NOT NULL
    AND d.id IS NULL
  GROUP  
     BY a.id;

+-------+------+
| start | cnt  |
+-------+------+
|  1201 |    3 |
|  1205 |    1 |
|  1207 |    2 |
|  1301 |    6 |
+-------+------+
```